# Call function of importing(!) python source in the imported one

Tags: python

Suppose I have some **main.py**

```
def sauce():
    print "This is the secret"

from included import magic
magic()
```

and **included.py**

```
def magic():
    sauce()
```

This should print *This is the secret* but of course it throws an error.

It's a bit vice versa to what generally is needed. But is there some secret sauce to achieve what I want?

Comment: It looks like you want the two modules to import each other, but you can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is lexically scoped; the name `sauce` in the definition of `magic` refers to a name in the global scope of `included` (where `magic` is defined), not the scope of wherever `magic` happens to be called.

A demonstration that this is so (and *not* a recommendation to write your code this way):

```
import included
from included import magic

def sauce_implementation():
    print "This is the secret"

included.sauce = sauce_implementation  # Patch the global scope of included

magic()
```

A better alternative is to have `magic` take a `sauce` argument, rather than relying on someone to provide a definition for its undefined global reference.